# Как выполнять один скрипт на двух страницах?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть две страницы, к которым подключён один файл со скриптом. Как сделать так, что бы функция `onclick` которую я подключил к определённой кнопке на первой странице, выполнила функцию и на другой странице? Например я нажал кнопку на странице index.html а функция выполнилась в текущей странице и в другой index2.html? (Моя функция меняет определённый текст) Для примера:
`function f1(){ document.getElementsByClassName("headerText")[0].innerHTML = "Helo World"; 
 }`

Функция `f1()` выполняется при нажатии на одну из кнопок на главной странице, точнее на index.html я хочу что бы она применилась на другой странице - index2.html, и див `headerText` который находится в ней, поменял свой текущий текст. Но когда я это делаю ничего не выходит... Прошу помочь)

Comment: "Но когда я это делаю" - что "это"? Где открыта вторая страница (она открыта?) в момент нажатия на кнопку на первой странице.

Comment: Да, страница открыта. Это - когда я нажимаю на кнопку

Comment: **Где** открыта вторая страница?

Comment: В браузере, в том же браузере что и первая.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь 3 варианта на мой взгляд:

1) сделать привязку через локальное хранилище или куки(и т.д) которые опрашивать периодами на предмет изменений (но это хардкор)

2) использовать вебсокеты и поменяв на одной странице в нужном месте поменять и на других. (это тоже хардкор)

3) использовать [web-workers широковещательный канал](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel) (но не все браузеры поддерживают)